# Cmder error when using msysgit tools

Tags: conemu, msysgit, cmder

Using cmder, every time I try to run one of the msysgit tools (e.g. ls) I get the following error:

> 0 [main] ls 7796 stdio_init: couldn't make stderr distinct from stdout

The same tools work fine from cmd.exe and git-bash, so I can't understand why it doesn't work in cmder. Cmder uses ConEmu, so that could also be the problem.

Cmder version: 1.2

ConEmu version: 20150513 preview

Git for Windows version: Git-1.9.5-preview20150319

Windows version: 7 (64-bit)

Git task command:

```
"%ConEmuDrive%\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe" --login -i -new_console
```

Comment: Neither version was specified.

Comment: Sorry, you're quite right. Have added version info now.

Comment: how do you run your git tab?

Comment: https://conemu.github.io/en/OldBuild.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm sorry I didn't realise I could update ConEmu from inside. I'll try this as soon as I get to the office in the morning.

Comment: Still seems to happen in version 150913 alpha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem most probably is not related to ConEmu or cmder.

Check that your tools (ls.exe) are used from the same location as bash.exe. Check your PATH variable.

Also, this may be related to TERM variable.

Anyway, you'll observe the same behavior if you run your bash.exe from Win+R.

Comment: You're quite right, getting rid of the msysgit tools bundled with Cmder (then using the ones from Git for Windows) has fixed this. Thanks!